# Why doesn't each_slice work?

Tags: ruby, api, enumerable, core-api

I am trying to use the Enumerable#each_slice. It doesn't work on my computer, stating that method is not found.

I am running ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0]

API: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003142

Example:

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a} # I get NoMethodError: undefined method `each_slice' for 1..10:Range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure the ruby-doc does not refer to ruby 1.9?

Comment: How do I figure that out? I don't see anything in the API stating the version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby 1.8.6 you have to `require 'enumerator'` (which is part of stdlib and has been merged into core in 1.8.7+) before using each_slice.

Sadly the ruby-doc lists methods that are added to core classes by stdlib without mentioning where the methods are from.

Comment: Thanks!
FYI, I tried <require 'enumerable'> and it gave me an exception. On the other hand, <require 'enumerator'> worked and the method was available.

Answer (score 1):

just compared 1.8.6 to 1.9 and it looks like

```
(1..10).respond_to? :each_slice
```

is true in 1.9 and false in 1.8.6. So, the doc you are using is not for 1.8.6. if you can upgrade to a newer version of Ruby easily it should give you that method on the Range.

Comment: Not true actually. The linked docs are for 1.8.6. The docs for 1.8.7 and 1.9 have core-1.8.7 and core-1.9 respectively instead of core in their url. It's just that the core docs also list methods that are added to core classes by files in stdlib (yes, that sucks).