# how to get an order-specified subset of an array of variable length from an array of variable length?

Tags: ruby, arrays, function

I have an array of objects of variable length n. Defined by the number of records in my database.

I need a function to grab subsets (keeping the objects in order and always beginning at index 0) of the array of specified length m where m can be any integer I pass in.

e.g. if n = 10 and m = 4

array foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

subset a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
subset b = [4, 5, 6, 7]
subset c = [8, 9]

So, I need to programmatically be able to say, "Give me the i-th subset of length m from an array, given the array is length n." Using the previous example: "Give me the second subset of length four from foo" => returns the items at positions [4, 5, 6, 7].

I hope that made sense. Assistance with a ruby solution would be much appreciated! thx!

Comment: Just for clarification: would the method signature look roughly like `def bar(subset_index, subset_length)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   foo.each_slice(subset_length).to_a[subset_index]
```

e.g. `foo.each_slice(4).to_a[2]` returns "the second subset of length four from foo".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable#each_slice`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].each_slice(4).to_a
#=> [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Comment: This language will never stop amazing me. However, a quote [from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293734/why-doesnt-each-slice-work) says one needs to `require 'enumerator'` in Ruby 1.8.6 for this solution to work. In 1.8.7 and 1.9 there are no problems.

Comment: thank you! JacobM got in just before you, so he got the check